# Multiple queries optimization in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have three models, User, Achievement and AchievementHistory

User Model looks like

```
User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Achievement Model looks like

```
Achievement(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

AchievementHistory Model looks like

```
AchievementHistory(models.Model):
     achievement = models.ForeignKey(Achievement, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     user = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I what to count every achievement of user. Say there are three achievements present like 'hello', 'world', 'goodbye' and user achieved 'hello' two times and world three times then i want output as this

```
{
    'hello': 2,
    'world': 3,
    'goodbye': 0,
}
```

i can find this by following function

```
def get_user_achievements_by_id(id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
    response = []
    for achievement in Achievement.objects.all():
        number_of_entries = AchievementHistory.objects.filter(
            user=user, achievement=achievement).count()
        response.append({str(achievement.title): number_of_entries})
    return response
```

Here actually three different queries performing. Is there any way we can reduce number of queries and actually in a single query.

Comment: use annotation query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#values). Something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count

AchievementHistory.objects.filter(user=user).values('achievement__title').annotate(
    Count('achievement__title')
).order_by()
```